# How to write these kinds of integrals in a more compact way?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, code-review

I wanted to calculate the average distance between two points both lying inside $B^2(\vec 0, R)$, and ended up writing

```
Clear[r1,r2,x,y,z,R,x1,x2,y1,y2,z1,z2]
Assuming[R>0,Integrate[Integrate[Sqrt[Abs[x1^2 +y1^2+z1^2 - x2^2 - y2^2 - z2^2]], {x1,y1,z1 }\[Element]Ball[{0,0,0},R]],{x2,y2,z2}\[Element]Ball[{0,0,0},R]]]
```

However, given the elegance of the Mathematica language, and any my experience in programming in general, I, sort of, felt ashamed of myself writing such ugly code.

Is there a more compact & elegant way of writing the same code in a short manner such that it will also improve the speed of the code? Because I run this code on wolframcloud and it couldn't find the result withing the limits of its execution time.

Comment: See also [Mean distance between 2 points within a sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/167932) on the Math SE.

Comment: @MarcoB thanks for the comment; I know how to calculate this quantity mathematically, but my main question is about the code rather than the mathematics that the code tries to compute.

Comment: But first of all the formula, you use is wrong. Let us start with that.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch the integrand? what is wrong exactly?

Comment: The integrand should use `(x1-x2)^2 + ...`, that is, the sum of square differences.

Comment: Look at `Norm[{x1, y1, z1} - {x2, y2, z2}]` or `Norm[{x1, y1, z1} - {x2, y2, z2}] // Simplify[#, Element[{x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2}, Reals]] &`